# How to pin all spaces efficiently?

Tags: autolayout, xcode5

When I need a view to fill its superview space, I add four constraints using Editor/Pin (some space) to superview.

After the constraint is added, the view is deselected, and you have to reselect it to add the next constraint.

Is there a faster way to achieve this, not neccessarily using the UI ? A solution using some auto layout snippet would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966792/1990236) should help you. You can also experiment with selecting the view and then clicking on "Reset to Suggested Constraints":

[image]

It's faster, but won't always create constraints you're looking for. Generated constraints are dependent on your view hierarchy.